# apollo-client server to server mutation causes error (query ok)

Tags: javascript, express, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

i'm using apollo-client on my web server to communicate with my graphql server (also apollo).  i have a successful query working and retrieving data properly, but when i attempt a mutation, i'm getting `new ApolloError` messages.  the same mutation copy/pasted into graphiql works perfectly.

i have checked CORS on my graphql server and it is enabled and functioning properly.  i've literally copied and pasted my mutation from the code into my graphiql editor and it works as expected.

can someone shed some light on this for me, or direct me to how i can see more information on my graphql-server about WHY i'm getting a `400` error?

here is the apollo error

```
{
  "graphQLErrors": [],
  "networkError": {
    "response": {
      "url": "http://localhost:9000/api/private",
      "status": 400,
      "statusText": "Bad Request",
      "headers": {
        "_headers": {
          "x-powered-by": [
            "Express"
          ],
          "access-control-allow-origin": [
            "*"
          ],
          "content-type": [
            "application/json"
          ],
          "date": [
            "Wed, 22 Mar 2017 05:36:21 GMT"
          ],
          "connection": [
            "close"
          ],
          "transfer-encoding": [
            "chunked"
          ]
        }
      },
      "ok": false,
      "body": {
        "_readableState": {
          "objectMode": false,
          "highWaterMark": 16384,
          "buffer": {
            "head": {
              "data": {
                "type": "Buffer",
                "data": [
                  123,
                  34,
                  101,
                  114,
                  114,
                  111,
                  114,
                  115,
                  34,
                  58,
                  91,
                  123,
                  34,
                  109,
                  101,
                  115,
                  115,
                  97,
                  103,
                  101,
                  34,
                  58,
                  34,
                  67,
                  97,
                  110,
                  110,
                  111,
                  116,
                  32,
                  113,
                  117,
                  101,
                  114,
                  121,
                  32,
                  102,
                  105,
                  101,
                  108,
                  100,
                  32,
                  92,
                  34,
                  116,
                  111,
                  107,
                  101,
                  110,
                  92,
                  34,
                  32,
                  111,
                  110,
                  32,
                  116,
                  121,
                  112,
                  101,
                  32,
                  92,
                  34,
                  85,
                  115,
                  101,
                  114,
                  83,
                  101,
                  114,
                  118,
                  105,
                  99,
                  101,
                  115,
                  92,
                  34,
                  46,
                  34,
                  44,
                  34,
                  108,
                  111,
                  99,
                  97,
                  116,
                  105,
                  111,
                  110,
                  115,
                  34,
                  58,
                  91,
                  123,
                  34,
                  108,
                  105,
                  110,
                  101,
                  34,
                  58,
                  57,
                  44,
                  34,
                  99,
                  111,
                  108,
                  117,
                  109,
                  110,
                  34,
                  58,
                  55,
                  125,
                  93,
                  125,
                  93,
                  125
                ]
              },
              "next": null
            },
            "tail": {
              "data": {
                "type": "Buffer",
                "data": [
                  123,
                  34,
                  101,
                  114,
                  114,
                  111,
                  114,
                  115,
                  34,
                  58,
                  91,
                  123,
                  34,
                  109,
                  101,
                  115,
                  115,
                  97,
                  103,
                  101,
                  34,
                  58,
                  34,
                  67,
                  97,
                  110,
                  110,
                  111,
                  116,
                  32,
                  113,
                  117,
                  101,
                  114,
                  121,
                  32,
                  102,
                  105,
                  101,
                  108,
                  100,
                  32,
                  92,
                  34,
                  116,
                  111,
                  107,
                  101,
                  110,
                  92,
                  34,
                  32,
                  111,
                  110,
                  32,
                  116,
                  121,
                  112,
                  101,
                  32,
                  92,
                  34,
                  85,
                  115,
                  101,
                  114,
                  83,
                  101,
                  114,
                  118,
                  105,
                  99,
                  101,
                  115,
                  92,
                  34,
                  46,
                  34,
                  44,
                  34,
                  108,
                  111,
                  99,
                  97,
                  116,
                  105,
                  111,
                  110,
                  115,
                  34,
                  58,
                  91,
                  123,
                  34,
                  108,
                  105,
                  110,
                  101,
                  34,
                  58,
                  57,
                  44,
                  34,
                  99,
                  111,
                  108,
                  117,
                  109,
                  110,
                  34,
                  58,
                  55,
                  125,
                  93,
                  125,
                  93,
                  125
                ]
              },
              "next": null
            },
            "length": 1
          },
          "length": 117,
          "pipes": null,
          "pipesCount": 0,
          "flowing": null,
          "ended": false,
          "endEmitted": false,
          "reading": true,
          "sync": false,
          "needReadable": true,
          "emittedReadable": true,
          "readableListening": false,
          "resumeScheduled": false,
          "defaultEncoding": "utf8",
          "ranOut": false,
          "awaitDrain": 0,
          "readingMore": false,
          "decoder": null,
          "encoding": null
        },
        "readable": true,
        "domain": null,
        "_events": {},
        "_eventsCount": 7,
        "_writableState": {
          "objectMode": false,
          "highWaterMark": 16384,
          "needDrain": false,
          "ending": false,
          "ended": false,
          "finished": false,
          "decodeStrings": true,
          "defaultEncoding": "utf8",
          "length": 0,
          "writing": false,
          "corked": 0,
          "sync": false,
          "bufferProcessing": false,
          "writecb": null,
          "writelen": 0,
          "bufferedRequest": null,
          "lastBufferedRequest": null,
          "pendingcb": 0,
          "prefinished": false,
          "errorEmitted": false,
          "bufferedRequestCount": 0,
          "corkedRequestsFree": {
            "next": null,
            "entry": null
          }
        },
        "writable": true,
        "allowHalfOpen": true,
        "_transformState": {
          "needTransform": true,
          "transforming": false,
          "writecb": null,
          "writechunk": null,
          "writeencoding": "buffer"
        }
      },
      "bodyUsed": false,
      "size": 0,
      "timeout": 0,
      "_raw": [],
      "_abort": false
    }
  },
  "message": "Network error: Network request failed with status 400 - \"Bad Request\""
}
Error
    at new ApolloError (/Users/rkstar/dev/projects/crate/microservices/dashboard/node_modules/apollo-client/apollo.umd.js:1490:23)
    at /Users/rkstar/dev/projects/crate/microservices/dashboard/node_modules/apollo-client/apollo.umd.js:2149:24
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

**** UPDATE ****
i added middleware before my `apolloMiddleware` to console.log the req.headers and req.body

```
req.headers -------
{
  "accept": "*/*",
  "content-type": "application/json",
  "authorization": "JWT ",
  "accept-encoding": "gzip,deflate",
  "user-agent": "node-fetch/1.0 (+https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch)",
  "connection": "close",
  "content-length": "585",
  "host": "localhost:9000"
}

req.body -------
{
  "query": "mutation updateTwitterAccessToken($data: TokenInput!) {\n  updateTwitterToken(data: $data) {\n    _id\n    services {\n      twitter {\n        id\n        __typename\n      }\n      token {\n        token\n        expires\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n",
  "variables": {
    "data": {
      "accessToken": "000700000-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "accessTokenSecret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "_id": "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
      "service": "twitter",
      "serviceId": "000700000"
    }
  },
  "operationName": "updateTwitterAccessToken"
}
```

i'm calling `client.mutate({ ... })` from my web server, but in the `req.body` here, i'm setting this:

```
req.body -------
{
  "query": "mutation ..."
....
}
```

why is it `"query": "mutation ..."` and not `"mutation": "mutation ..."` ?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

i solved the problem and it was because my `update-token.graphql` file had a return property improperly nested === error.

---

OKAY... so i solved this problem.  it was a silly error in my graphql mutation.  i was trying to get a field that didn't exist within another field.

i had copied and pasted my query into graphiql where it worked fine!  what i had forgotten was that i un-nested one of my return vars which made all the difference.  i thought i had pasted my changes back to the `.graphql` file... but apparently not.

what's INTERESTING about this is how i finally figured out this error:

i tried adding middleware to print out my request -------

```
router.all('/private',
  bodyParser.json(),
  (req, res, next)=>{
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.route, null, 2))
    next()
  },
  apolloMiddleware
)
```

that showed me lots of things, but nothing jumped out at me when comparing the request from graphiql vs. apollo-client (probably because the actual query was a string and not formatted like nice json)

then i finally came upon `formatError` which i was able to have print out my error:

```
const apolloMiddleware: any = graphqlExpress(request => ({
  debug: debugMode,
  schema: executableSchema,
  context: request,
  formatError: e =>{
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e, null, 2))
  }
}))
```

and THAT showed me this:

```
{
  "message": "Cannot query field \"token\" on type \"UserServices\".",
  "locations": [
    {
      "line": 9,
      "column": 7
    }
  ]
}
```

after seeing this message, i promptly updated my `.graphql` file and did an epic facepalm as i watched the mutation work as expected via apollo-client.